# VueJS dynamic v-model value

Tags: vue.js

I want to set `v-model` to a value dictated by the value in my `v-for` loop.
here's my code:

```
<tr v-for="campaign in _campaigns">
    <el-switch v-model="campaign.enabled"></el-switch>
</tr>
```

now if `campaign.enabled === 'active'` i want to set v-model to on , or if
 `campaign.enabled === 'inactive'` than off.

i tried to add logic to v-model in few ways like:
`v-model="campaign.enabled === 'active' ? on : off"` or to use a method but none worked. Any idea what will consider as best practice to achieve that?

Comment: el-swith is this component? https://github.com/freeze-component/el-switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-model` needs to be able to assign to its argument as well as read its value. The values it expects to receive and assign are booleans. Since you want to convert those to strings you will need to have methods to encode and convert the values, and you will need to separate the `v-model` into its component `value` and `on:input` bindings.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    campaigns: [{
      enabled: 'active'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    decodeCampaign(c) {
      return c.enabled === 'active';
    },
    encodeCampaign(b) {
      return b ? 'active' : 'inactive';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/1.4.0/index.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/1.4.0/theme-default/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="campaign in campaigns">
    <el-switch :value="decodeCampaign(campaign)" @input="(v) => campaign.enabled = encodeCampaign(v)"></el-switch>
    {{campaign.enabled}}
  </div>
</div>
```

If you didn't have an array, you could use the encode and decode to implement a settable computed, and use `v-model` with it, but there's no good way to make a computed for each element of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr v-for="campaign in _campaigns">
    <el-switch v-model="campaign.enabled === 'active'"></el-switch>
</tr>
```

docs says you have to provide an boolean to the v-model:
http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/switch1

Comment: this gives an error `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue`

Comment: could you please post your entire code, or create a fiddle?

Comment: `v-model` is two-way binding, which means it will try to assign to it when the switch is flipped.

Answer (score 0):

The directive `v-model` is limited to the input types

- `<input>`
- `<select>`
- `<textarea>`
- and vue components

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model

So a bool value will work for `<input type="radio" ...>` and `type="checkbox"` you cannot set

> set v-model to on

you can only set an input to checked or unchecked. If you want to disable or hide the component use `v-if` or `v-show`.

You are trying to use v-model on a component, so you should read this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events or https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components . In most cases i think using props in the component would be the better solution. Because v-model is the standard two way binding directive.